# Disabling the inner-border of an Aero Glass form

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, windows-vista, aero

Controls on an Aero Glass enabled form paint a 2 pixel wide transparent border by default (1px dark gray/1px white on my theme). Is it possible to disable this behavior?

My approach so far: I tried expanding the frame and force it to use the complete form area (DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea and negative margins), however, although this removes the unwanted borders, it also seems to make all child controls "glassified" regardless of any background or z-order. Can certain regions be excluded from using Aero Glass with the extended frame?

Ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: Winforms and glass are water and fire.  Too many controls render using GDI, it uses 24bpp and doesn't set the alpha correctly.  There is no decent fix for this, consider WPF instead.

Comment: I would try my best at putting a solid background on that form. My first and most simple thought would be to add a panel and put all controls on this. Does that create magic "holes" in the panel where the controls would render, causing glass to shine through?